# Calculating expanding mean on 2 columns simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I have a table of 2 players competing each other:

```
    date         plA    plB    ptsA ptsB
0   01/01/2013  Jeff    Tom     78  72
1   15/01/2013  Jeff    Tom     52  67
2   01/02/2013  Tom     Jeff    91  93
3   15/02/2013  Jeff    Tom     83  87
4   01/03/2013  Tom     Jeff    65  76
```

I want to apply the expanding mean, such that `ptsA` and `ptsB` for each player get counted in (and are not left) to the net result. Final output should make it more clear:

```
    date         plA    plB    ptsA ptsB   meanA  meanB 
0   01/01/2013  Jeff    Tom     78  72      78     72      # init mean
1   15/01/2013  Jeff    Tom     52  67      65     69.5 
2   01/02/2013  Tom     Jeff    91  93      74.3   76.6    # Tom: (72+67+91)/3, Jeff: (78+52+93)/3
3   15/02/2013  Jeff    Tom     83  87      76.5   79.25   # Jeff: (78+52+93+83)/4, Tom: (72+67+91+87)/4
4   01/03/2013  Tom     Jeff    65  76      76.4   76.4    # Tom: (72+67+91+87+65)/5, Jeff: (78+52+93+83+76)/5
```

Now, I started grouping data by `plA` and like this:

```
by_A = players.sort(columns='date').groupby('plA')
players['meanA'] = by_A['ptsA'].apply(pd.expanding_mean)
players['meanB'] = by_A['ptsB'].apply(pd.expanding_mean)
```

and obviously, I need to do the same, and `groupby('plB')` and then Im drawing a blank how to join these two results correctly.

Perhaps pandas offers a built-in or you have a solution for it?

@EDIT Saullo Castro's solution with slightly different data

```
    date    studentA    studentB    scoreA  scoreB  meanJeff    meanTom     meanMaggie
0   2013-01-01  Jeff    Tom     78  72             78.000000    72.000000   0.000000
1   2013-01-15  Jeff    Maggie  52  67             65.000000    36.000000   33.500000
2   2013-02-01  Tom     Jeff    91  93             74.333333    54.333333   22.333333
3   2013-02-15  Jeff    Tom     83  87             76.500000    62.500000   16.750000
4   2013-03-01  Tom     Jeff    65  76             76.400000    63.000000   13.400000
```

Maggie's mean should stay `67` all the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(Please, refer to the fixed solution below)**

One approach is to find out all the player's names first:

```
names = pd.concat((df.plA, df.plB)).unique()
```

Then create one new column with the expanding mean for each player:

```
for name in names:
    df['mean'+name] = pd.expanding_mean(df.ptsA*(df.plA==name) + df.ptsB*(df.plB==name))
```

Resulting in:

```
                  date   plA   plB  ptsA  ptsB   meanJeff    meanTom
0  2013-01-01 00:00:00  Jeff   Tom    78    72  78.000000  72.000000
1           15/01/2013  Jeff   Tom    52    67  65.000000  69.500000
2  2013-01-02 00:00:00   Tom  Jeff    91    93  74.333333  76.666667
3           15/02/2013  Jeff   Tom    83    87  76.500000  79.250000
4  2013-01-03 00:00:00   Tom  Jeff    65    76  76.400000  76.400000
```

---

EDIT: Fixed solution:

For more than two names this is how you can build the formula for the expanding mean:

```
df = pd.read_excel('stack.xlsx', 'tabelle1')
names = pd.concat((df.plA, df.plB)).unique()
for name in names:
    nA = df.plA==name
    nB = df.plB==name
    df['mean'+name] = np.cumsum(df.ptsA*nA + df.ptsB*nB)/np.maximum(1.,
                                     np.cumsum(1.*np.logical_or(nA, nB)))
```

Resulting in:

```
date   plA     plB  ptsA  ptsB   meanJeff    meanTom  meanMaggie
0 2013-01-01 00:00:00  Jeff     Tom    78    72  78.000000  72.000000     0
1 2013-01-15 00:00:00  Jeff  Maggie    52    67  65.000000  72.000000    67
2 2013-02-01 00:00:00   Tom    Jeff    91    93  74.333333  81.500000    67
3 2013-02-15 00:00:00  Jeff     Tom    83    87  76.500000  83.333333    67
4 2013-03-01 00:00:00   Tom    Jeff    65    76  76.400000  78.750000    67
```

Comment: Hi, this is possibly some good hint, but it fails if any of the players name gets substituted with a new one. Results will be completely wrong. See my updated post.

Comment: @nutship well observed... I'm trying to figure out another solution

Comment: Thanks again for taking the effort to update (+1 ofc). Based on your first answer, I came up with with similar, (to your fixed solution) and perhaps easier to understand, solution `for name in names:
    mask = st.scA*(st.plA==name) + st.scB*(st.plB==name)
    st['mean' + name] = pd.expanding_mean(mask[mask > 0])`. Anyways, I am hesitating to accept your answer, because the output format is not particularly convenient. With more players, the table gets broad. Ideally, there should be only two new columns `mean_plA`, `mean_plB` with values depending on who the 2 actual players are.

Comment: I will go ahead and accept the answer after all, as, thanks to your help, I managed to figured it out to a satisfactory extent ;)

Comment: @nutship Hey, good to hear that, you should post another answer with your simplified solution, it is always good to serve as a reference later on...

Comment: I changed the requirements, it no longer suits the topic, so I have not really solved the case in question.